# Getting all dirs/files in a folder

Tags: c#, io

I'm just going to have a tree view of a root folder, I use following recursive function but I think there is a problem with the return value of the function so that I cannot have all files/folders, and some child files/folders are missing:

```
 public string DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        string result = "";
        string physicalPath = sDir;
        if (sDir == "")
        {
            sDir = "~";
            physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(sDir);
        }
        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(physicalPath))
            {
                result += d;
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                {
                    result += f + ",";
                }
                result += ";";
                DirSearch(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {

        }
        return result;
    }
```

What is going wrong here? Any problem with the return value of function?

Comment: What do you expect to do with the string?  other than you didnt add the recursive calls to DirSearch to the string...

Comment: _I think some child files/folders are missing_ you think so or are you sure?

Comment: If you aren't sure if you have a problem then I suggest you test it. Once you have tested it and identified a problem then debug your code to find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Well I'm sure that child files/folders are missing!

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: Then put that in the question! :)

Comment: Thanks Chris! Question is now edited to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
       result += ";";
        DirSearch(d);
```

You do searches on subfolders, but dont add it to the result, eg,

```
       result += ";" + DirSearch(d);
```

Comment: Username checks out. ;-)

Comment: Yes, many thanks, you are reaaaaaaaaaaaally a bugFinder, how couldn't I just notice this problem!!!!